# Create student roster from Classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm trying to pull the student information from a google classroom roster. Here is what I have so far:

```
function studentRoster() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    pageSize: 2
  };
  var getStudents = Classroom.Courses.Students.list("757828465",optionalArgs).students;
  Logger.log(getStudents);
}
```

Sandy's answer below helped solve part of my problem and I get this as a log (names, id's, emails and such changed):

> [16-01-05 17:44:04:734 PST] [{profile={photoUrl=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg, emailAddress=jsdoe@fjuhsd.org, name={givenName=John, familyName=Doe, fullName=John Doe}, id=108117124004883828162}, courseId=757828465, userId=108117124004883828162}, {profile={photoUrl=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg, emailAddress=jhdoe@fjuhsd.org, name={givenName=Jane, familyName=Doe, fullName=Jane Doe}, id=115613162385930536688}, courseId=757828465, userId=115613162385930536688}]

So my question now is: How do I extract only certain pieces of this information (like full name and email)?

The end result will be pushing it to a google sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Collection sections under the Classroom API Reference can help clarify some of the object chaining required to access the fields you want.

The following code will generate a list of student names, their email, and associated course ID.

```html
function listStudents() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    pageSize: 0     // Max output
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.Students.list(xxxxxxxxx; // Put CourseID here
  var students = response.students;
  if(students && students.length > 0){
    for( i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
     var student = students[i];
     // fullName is normally prefixed with s/      use of .substring removes first two characters
     Logger.log('%s %s %s',  student.profile.name.fullName.substring(2), student.profile.emailAddress, student.courseId    );
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No students in this course');
  } 
}
```

[Collection courses.students](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students)

Comment: Ok, I can follow that. I'll give it a run and I'll update. Thank you!

Comment: It worked! Exactly what I was going for! Now I can move on to the next step. The substring was not needed, as it cut off the first two letters of their names. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The Quickstart example is using the `list` method, and the `list` method takes optional query parameters.  One of them being `pageSize`.

[Query parameters for List](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list#query-parameters)

You are using the `get` method.

[Documentation - Get method](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/get)

The only options that the `get` method has is for the `Path`. And there is only one setting, the `id`.

So, that object literal named `optionalArgs`, you don't need for what you are doing.  `optionalArgs` is an object because it has curly braces, and has elements that are "key/value" pairs.  It's "literal", because it's typed into the code, as opposed to building the object with code.

If you did a search, (open the search dialog with Ctrl + F), and searched for `optionalArgs`, you'll see that it's not being used anywhere.  So, the `optionalArgs` object with the `pageSize` property is not needed when using the `get` method.